# How to add Struts 1.x to Eclipse Java EE?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, struts, struts-config

I download eclipse java EE from eclipse.org and download struts 1.3 from apache.org.
Now I want to add struts framework to eclipse so that i can use struts library. I read many pages but each one says something which is different from other one.
Does anyone know how to add this plugin to eclipse and config struts?
Is it possible with these version of struts and eclipse or I have to download another version?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Dynamic Web Project from eclipse with the name you want and add the struts libraries from the Struts-distribution you have downloaded from the struts web site. Now follow these steps http://www.roseindia.net/blog/2007/12/18/struts-step-by-step/index.html and your struts application will be up and running.
       Hope this is what you were looking for.
Regards,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps----

JavaEE(File->import->Web(war file)->give the location of struts war->give your app name)

Finish..

Now your application is struts configured..